# Is there a way to stop a particular div container from overflowing when the webpage is responsive?

Tags: html, css, height

I have a parent element with a class(**.section2)** that have  two div containers with the class **(.menu-box1 )** that are its children, and I  used display: flex; and a flex-direction: column; and those two div containers have there one child containers with the class **(.menu)** set. But this containers are overflowing to the next sibling of their  parent element **(section3)**.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal code snippet of the code you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove any fixed height/width if you are giving.

With flexbox, the content will be within parent only.

```css
.section2{
  background-color:red;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  padding:15px
}

.menu-box1{
  background-color:yellow;
}

.menu{
  background-color:green;
}

.section3{
  position:relative;
  background-color:blue;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section2">
  <div class="menu-box1">
    <div class="menu">
      i am menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-box1">
    <div class="menu">
      random long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section3">
  I am section 3.
</div>
```